# Android - how can I disable fcm notification message on top bar programmatically?

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, disable

I made an android app using fcm subscribed to topic.

And here is a part of my code in `FirebaseMessagingService`.

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        mApplication = (ApplicationAVL)getApplication();
        Log.d("FCM received === ", "ok");

    

         cancelNotification();
        ApplicationAVL mApplication = (ApplicationAVL) getApplication();
        checkPollingService = isMyServiceRunning(AVLPollingService.class);

        if(!mApplication.isPollingNow() || !checkPollingService){
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new FcmToPollingEvent());
        }
    }
```

There is no codes for notification, but notification message always show also after closed app.

- `cancelNotification()` is a method for remove notification I tried, but it doesn't work.

  `public void cancelNotification(){ String ns = NOTIFICATION_SERVICE; NotificationManager nMgr = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(ns); nMgr.cancelAll(); }`

UnsubscribeToTopic `onDestory`, but it doesn't work, neither.

How can I disable fcm notification ??

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand you question. Based on the title of the question, the answer is to work on the message(payload) which comes from server or other source. put "silent":"true" in data message as the following example:

{
    "data": {
      "title": "afruz",
        "body" : "hello!",
        "silent":"true"
     }
    "registration_ids" : [""]
}

The push notification will invoke onMessageReceived without any message showing on top bar.

If you concern about unsubscribing topic from fcm, you can try to do it at application onPaused instead of onDestroid.

Hopefully, my answer is helpful to you.